# How to use Fabric using ssh_config's ProxyCommand and corkscrew?

Tags: proxy, ssh, firewall, fabric

I'm deploying a site to an server, but the port 22 is blocked at my office. I can now use `corkscrew` with the `ssh_config` `ProxyCommand` directive, and everything works fine, just connect using `$ ssh my_server_alias_in_sshconfig`.

Now I need to use Fabric to ease deployment, but even when setting `env.use_ssh_config=True` it doesn't work, it just looked up the IP address of the server and tried to connect directly, ignoring `ProxyCommand` and everything else. The Fabric docs says it leverages some of the config settings available, but without using `ProxyCommand`, Fabric seems useless here.

Any help?

I got this [gist](https://gist.github.com/856179), but I don't think it solves the `ProxyCommand` requirement.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, I set up a `LocalForward` directive like:

```
Host my_server_using_corkscrew
    ProxyCommand ...
    ...
    LocalForward 1122 localhost:22
```

And below:

```
Host my_server_using_corkscrew.localtunnel
    Hostname localhost
    Port 1122
```

And then, run Fabric with:

```
$ fab my_deploy_command --hosts=my_server_using_corkscrew.localtunnel
```

This has two inconveniences:

- I need to start the "tunnel" first with `$ ssh my_server_using_corkscrew` and leave it open.
- Inside the fabfile, the hostname is always `localhost`, so it can be a problem when deploying to multiple servers at once.

I'm using this for the time, but, can this be improved?

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 1):

A better workaround but still not perfect:

```
Host somebox
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket/%r@%h:%p
```

Then `$ ssh somebox` first and leave it open, then `$ fab -H somebox deploy` and the traffic will go through the sock and so it'll respect the ProxyCommand.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  For me, fabric does pick up the host config, but does not use the existing connection.  I even tried running a Fabric task that slept for 1 day and left it open, but that didn't share it's connection with other Fabric processes.